# seaborn keeping all my variable labels on the X scale

Tags: python, graph, label, seaborn

I am trying to plot some distribution boxes.

I uploaded my dataset, selected a few countries using the isin method.

When I run the seaborn boxplot command below, instead of having only 6 countries, I have all the 150 countries of the original dataset.

How do I keep only my 6 countries of interest?

```
ersa = pd.read_excel(data)

country = ['Bangladesh', 'China', 'Viet Nam', 'India', 'Cambodia', 'Malaysia']
ersa_source = ersa[ersa['Country'].isin(country)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(11, 11.27)
sns.set_style('white')
pal = sns.color_palette('Paired')
b = sns.boxplot(x='Country', y='Weekly hours (average)',
            data= ersa_source, width=0.5, palette= pal)
b =sns.stripplot(x='Country', y='Weekly hours (average)', 
                   data = ersa_source, 
                   jitter=True, 
                   linewidth = 1, 
                   alpha=0.6,  dodge=True,
                   palette = pal)
b= sns.despine(offset=10, trim=True)
ax.set_title('Title', fontsize = 20)
ax.set_xlabel('Country', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_ylabel("Y", fontsize = 15)
```

[image]

Comment: You do seem have 6 inputs. Could you try to switch x and y and in this way the labels won’t be overlapped.

Comment: Hi there, I tried, but the same problem happens on the y axis

Comment: I think the problem might be that your variable is categorical, in which `.isin()` will return `0` even for the unobserved [categories](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.0/generated/pandas.Categorical.value_counts.html). just try to convert them to string variable, or use `cat.remove_unused_categories()` to remove those categories.

Comment: yes! this is it!